# How to use BetterTouchTool to show Mail.app unread count in touch bar

Tags: touch-bar, bettertouchtool

I have a MacBook Pro with a touch bar and have never used BetterTouchTool. I know it has touch bar functionality, like adding a button to open an app. Is it possible to show either of the following?

- The Mail.app icon (with unread email count)
- Just the number of unread emails

If so, how can it be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BetterTouchTool has a "widget" option for the touch bar, and one of the options is to display the output of an AppleScript program. You could write a script that gets the number of unread emails (another question has some code for doing that [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/script-that-outputs-number-of-emails-in-mail-app-inbox))

[image]